# Unity disable particle system when outside of camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, particles

I am making a 2D game in unity that has an underwater theme. To make it look really pretty, I use a script to spawn glowy objects at random locations in the map. These objects are blank sprites with Particle Systems attached to them.

The problem is, I have about 100 of them active in the map at a time, and though it looks really pretty, the game lags on computers that don't have an i5 processor or faster.

The solution I thought of was to disable the objects while they are out of camera bounds so there is only about 4 or 5 active at a time...

Here's my script:

```
void Update () {

    if (this.transform.position.x < Camera.main.transform.position.x + 13 && this.transform.position.x > Camera.main.transform.position.x - 13 && this.transform.position.y < Camera.main.transform.position.y + 13 && this.transform.position.y > Camera.main.transform.position.y - 13) {             this.gameObject.particleEmitter.emit = true;
        this.gameObject.particleSystem.Play ();


            } 

    else {

        this.gameObject.particleSystem.Pause ();


    }
}
```

Ok, it checks if the object is outside the camera bounds correctly, but when it comes to disabling the object, I get this error:

"NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Pleade use unity3d tag.

Comment: Can you at least narrow down which reference is null? Stepping through with a debugger should help - though to be honest I've not used Unity's debugger, but I'm assuming it can do this.

Comment: Ok, I have tried declaring the Particle System at the top of the code with public "ParticleSystem Glow" and then used : Glow.enableEmission = true/false. THis removes the error but now the code just plain doesn't work... The particle systems attached to the blank instanitated prefabs should be invisible when outside the camera... But they aren't...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use both `particleEmitter`, which refers to the legacy particle system, and `particleSystem`, which refers to the new Souriken system. You're probably only using Souriken particles, so I would rewrite it like this:

```
void Update ()
{
    if (this.transform.position.x < Camera.main.transform.position.x + 13
        && this.transform.position.x > Camera.main.transform.position.x - 13
        && this.transform.position.y < Camera.main.transform.position.y + 13
        && this.transform.position.y > Camera.main.transform.position.y - 13)
    {
        particleSystem.Play ();
    } 
    else
    {
        particleSystem.Pause ();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer. The weird thing is, I actually already found another solution (after hours of searching and experimenting) LOL. Here's what I came up with:

  if (this.transform.position.x < Camera.main.transform.position.x + 16 etc etc) { 

   foreach(Transform child in this.transform)
  child.gameObject.active=child.gameObject.active;





    } 
  else {

  foreach(Transform child in this.transform)
  child.gameObject.active=!child.gameObject.active;